# Datasource Connection Pool?

Tags: datasource

On different sites it is written that, datasource maintain the connection pool. Yes i agree it will maintain the pool
if we dont close the connection once we are done with transaction. But generally we close the connection once we are done
with transaction. So practically  datasource will never have any connection to maintain the pool. Is this correct?
It will be the scenario only when programmer forget to close the connection.Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection pool maintains open connections for a certain period of time and usually closes them after some time of inactivity. Forgetting to close a connection prevents it from being released back to the pool and later reused, that's why you should *always* close them. What is the question anyways?

Comment: My question is if we close the connection, will it be moved back to pool? if yes , what is use of moving the closed connectio to pool?My understanding is that when programmer forget to close the connection  datasource will move the open connection to pool after some time automatically. Is this correct?

Comment: No, this is not correct. It will never move back to the pool and will cause a connection leak. If you close the connection then yes, it goes back to the pool and that is the right thing to do.

Comment: hi Otavio , what is the advantage of moving the closed connection to pool?

Comment: Closing the connection moves it back to the pool so the next request for Open will reuse it (or any other available). That's the whole point of having a pool - don't spend time physically opening and closing connections.

Comment: Hi Otavio, Is this management of getting the connection and moving back the connection to pool is done by Datasource (which internally is handled by app server)? In case we dont use the datasource closing the connection willphysically close the connection. Right?

Comment: I don't think so. The connection pool is managed by the underlying driver and you would not be able to physically close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this is MS .NET, as long as the connection string is identical, the web server will pool the connections automatically. This will occur even if you 'close' them, so it is very efficient.